# SwiftUI - Want to animate the circumference while keeping the view orientation fixed

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hellow

I want to animate the circumference while keeping the view orientation fixed.

I used `rotationEffect` to move it in a circle.
But View is always looking forward.

```
struct RotateObjectInEllipsePath: View {
    
  let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
  let circleWidth: CGFloat = 250.0
  
  @State private var angle: Double = .zero
  @State private var ellipseX: CGFloat = .zero
  @State private var handling: Bool = false
  @State private var imageAngle: Double = .zero
    
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Circle()
        .strokeBorder(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
        .frame(width: circleWidth, height: circleWidth)
      
      
      Circle()
        .foregroundColor(.purple)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .offset(x: circleWidth/2)
        .overlay(
          Text("Hi")
            .offset(x: circleWidth/2)
        )
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
          angle += 1
        }
        .animation(.default)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle))
    }
  }
}

struct RotateObjectInEllipsePath_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RotateObjectInEllipsePath()
    }
}
```

I always want to straighten the letter Hi and move it.
Do you know a good way?

Debug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGNUg.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the counter-rotation to the text to compensate:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Circle()
        .strokeBorder(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
        .frame(width: circleWidth, height: circleWidth)
      Circle()
        .foregroundColor(.purple)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .overlay(
          Text("Hi")
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-angle))
        ).offset(x: circleWidth/2)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
          angle += 1
        }
        .animation(.default)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle))
    }
  }
```

It should look like this:

[image: with counter-rotated text]

Comment: Thank you for your help.
This code is perfect!!